How to mark a input field required when I select any value from a dropdown list in Angular 17 reactive form?
I have a dropdown list of 5 items.Whenever I choose a value from it one of my input fields will be marked as required. Otherwise the input field will be a non mandatory field.
How to dynamically mark the field as mandatory whenever a value is selected from the dropdown. I need a solution for the problem.

You can use valueChanges subscription to add or remove validator functions on input fields. Have a look at Sample Code below for better understanding and Please correct me if I am missing something.
HTML-
<div class="d-flex p-5 align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">

    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label for="name">Required Field:</label>
            <select id="name" formControlName="requiredField" class="form-control">
                <option value="name">Name</option>
                <option value="email">Email</option>
                <option value="address">Address</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label for="name">Name<span
                    class="text-danger">{{myForm.get('requiredField')?.value=='name'?'*':''}}</span>:</label>
            <input id="name" formControlName="name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label for="email">Email<span
                    class="text-danger">{{myForm.get('requiredField')?.value=='email'?'*':''}}</span>:</label>
            <input id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label for="address">Address<span
                    class="text-danger">{{myForm.get('requiredField')?.value=='address'?'*':''}}</span>:</label>
            <input id="address" formControlName="address" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

</div>

TS-
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  sub: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      requiredField: ['name'],
      name: ['',Validators.required],
      email: [''],
      address: [''],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.myForm.get('requiredField')?.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach(key => {
        if (this.myForm.controls[key].hasValidator(Validators.required)) {
          this.myForm.controls[key].removeValidators(Validators.required);
        }
      })
      this.myForm.controls[value].addValidators(Validators.required);
    })
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    if (this.myForm.invalid) {
      alert("Please provide required information");
    } else {
      console.log(this.myForm.value);
    }
  }
}


